# Force Lambda Function to Fail

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I want to ensure a Lambda function fails when certain conditions are met.

After some Googling I ended up with variations on the below code, but even in the Lambda UI, when I 'test' , it still succeeds and simply spits the json out as as a response.

Ultimately I will be invoking the function from Terraform, and I need a solid fail in order to prevent subsequent code from continuing.

Any guidance appreciated :)

```
def lambda_handler(event, context):
    x = 'dummy'
    
    return {
        "isBase64Encoded" : True,
        "statusCode": "400",
        "headers": {},
        "body": "My error text"
}
```

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "fail"? What is the process you will use to run the code, and what exactly do you expect to happen when you do this?

Comment: Exact use case : invoking the function with Terraform : data "aws_lambda_invocation" "myfunction" ... and having TF recognise it as a failure.

Answer (score 0):

What I get is, you want to fail the Lambda function to send the response as 400 from the connected API Gateway.

With your current settings, response is not completely managed by the Lambda function, but interpreted by the API Gateway, that eventually sends 200 status for your function.

To let the Lambda function handle response and failure programmatically, use Lambda Integrations. You'll get the response that you returned in the code (400 in your case) and Lambda function itself will succeed (as it did what was needed to be done).

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/getting-started-with-lambda-integration.html

Let me know if it helps.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you correctly you want to make your lambda function fail when using `data "aws_lambda_invocation"`.
Maybe you can forward some 'fail' parameter over lambda_handler attributes.

taken from here:
https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/data-sources/lambda_invocation

```
data "aws_lambda_invocation" "example" {
  function_name = aws_lambda_function.lambda_function_test.function_name

  input = <<JSON
{
  "key1": "value1",
  "key2": "value2"
}
JSON
}

output "result_entry" {
  value = jsondecode(data.aws_lambda_invocation.example.result)["key1"]
}
```

After you recieve the parameter you can either raise an Exception or return wanted response.

In my case I wanted to test failure of lambda after it was created (during runtime) so I took the `fail` parameter from lambda env variable.